# Value must be ≥ 0 but getColumnIndex can be -1

Tags: crash

```
assert uri != null;
        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uri,projection,MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + " = \"" + file.getAbsolutePath()+ "\"", null, null);
        String strRingtone = null, strAlarm = null, strNotifi = null, strMusic = null;
        try{
            while (true) {
            assert c != null;
            if (!c.moveToNext()) break;
            strRingtone = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE));
            strAlarm = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM));
            strNotifi = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION));
            strMusic = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC));
        }
            } finally {
            assert c != null;
            c.close();
        }
```

when run the app after click play on first track the app is crash

Comment: The values must be >= 0, returns -1 if not found.